# How to use multiple connections one by module in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating an application in Laravel where each one will have its database, is it possible for each module to receive its connection file instead of leaving everything inside the config/database?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but why would you like to save separately? Yo can have multiple database configuration "blocks", and manage everything from your `.env` file. Thats the way I do that.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to do that, you can create multiple connections and use different connection for different modules you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278456/laravel-change-connection-in-model-for-one-method/52278701) for more details.

Comment: @Sebastián Pérez
because i know i will have countless connections and so i thought it would be simpler to organize, because i would already know that the connection would be inside the module itself

Comment: you might want to look into microservices. from the looks of it you might want to try another architecture altogether.

Comment: @PrateikDarji as I said above I thought it would be the best way to organize ... I'm new to Laravel I still don't know all the best ways to work on it

Comment: Ok, maybe you can try this workaround (not sure if it works, and also is no elegant, but can works). You can create a table in your principal database called `connections`. And save all connection values. Then, you can import \DB in your `config/databases`, and make an `array push` for each connection into the `connections` array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel, change connection in model for one method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278456/laravel-change-connection-in-model-for-one-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say module what do you mean by that?

Laravel supports multiple db connections, and in each Eloquent model you can add property $connection to specify which database connection to use for a specific model.

```
class MyClass extends Eloquent {

    protected $connection = 'myConnectionName';
    ...
}
```

make sure that all models that are in relations are within the same database though.
Add defintion of myConnectionName in config/database.php

Comment: I mean working with nwidart / laravel-modules, to create application modules within my main project ....
but from what I'm seeing it won't be possible to work the way I imagined ... I'll have to create the connections in .env and config / database

Comment: Yes, I would stick to standard Laravel has set up, any changes in the standard would mean mess in maintenance later on. Because eloquent is so tightly couple with database it is a bit of a problem setting up db connections on the side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible follow the following step and let me if any query

Step 1 : Add the second db code in config->database.php bottom of mysql=>[....]

```
'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST2', '100.10.0.100'),  // note add your hostname 
            'port' => env('DB_PORT2', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE2', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME2', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD2', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Step 2 : Add the code in .evn file

```
DB_CONNECTION2=mysql
DB_HOST2=100.10.0.100 // Add your hostname
DB_PORT2=3306
DB_DATABASE2=test // add your DB name
DB_USERNAME2=testuser // add your user name
DB_PASSWORD2=test123 // add your pass
```

Step 3 : you can access in controller like (Note : use youe table name and fields)

```
$records= DB::connection('mysql2');       
       $records1 = $records->table('contact');
       $records2 = $records1->where('mobile',$client_mob)
                   ->where('delete',0)
                   ->first(['id','converted']);
```

All the best...